# Attributing Wikipedia articles in a book

Tags: creative-commons, attribution

I have written a book. It is a collection of texts copied from Wikipedia articles. Then I attach multiple-choice questions for checking students' reading comprehension.

Is it enough if I state that texts are taken from Wikipedia.org at the end of the book, or do I have to provide the URL after each and every article?

Comment: Relevant: [Wikipedia:Reusing Wikipedia content](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Reusing_Wikipedia_content)

Answer (score 1):

Wikipedia text is licensed under the Creative Commons Share-Alike Attribution license, or CC BY-SA for short. Quick note, images aren't always licensed under this license - they can be under more restrictive or permissive licenses that can limit your usage of them.

With this [Open Source post](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/1727/how-to-attribute-creative-commons-images-in-a-quiz-game-mobile-app), there is no required way to do this, however, there are a few guidelines on this:

> Books, journals and magazines
>
> • Include the relevant attribution information next to the CC work or as a footer along the bottom of the work on the page that the work appears on; and
>
> • Alternatively, you can list the CC works in the back of the publication. If you take this option, it is best to list the works in the order in which they appear in the publication and indicate this to the reader.

So you can attribute the articles at the end of the publication.

However, you do need to make it clear **what** content is taken, **where** it was taken from, and **where** it is in your publication. Simply having a list of raw links would not necessarily be sufficient - what came from where?

If your publication is divided by section, then you should organize it. Here would be an example:

> **Section 1:**
> Urban Planning: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urban_planning
> Civil Engineering: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Civil_engineering
> Public Administration: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_administration

And so on. This way, you are clear as to what content is taken, and where it was taken from.

Comment: Would it be sufficient just to write that all texts are taken from Wikipedia.org instead of pointing to each article's URL one by one?

Comment: @Muzaffar It's not sufficient, because you need to have a link to the source. The licences are fairly clear on that.

Comment: It’s also necessary to reproduce the licence text, or at least give a link to it.